# Java: Check variable type

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment where I have to sort integers and string type variables.

So I have a method declared as

```
public void quickSort(ArrayList<Entry<Integer, String>> list) {
```

but if I want to overload the method and use

```
public void quickSort(ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>> list) {
```

It is recognized as a duplicate.

Is there a way to check what my variable types are? 
Alternatively, is there a way to sort strings and integers the same way so that I can do something like

```
public void quickSort(ArrayList<Entry<K, V>> list) {
```

that will work on both date types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to provide an explicit comparator, since there is no natural ordering of `Entry`s:

```
public <T> void quickSort(ArrayList<T> list, Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

and then use that `comparator` inside the method for your comparisons.

The fact that you are trying to sort something with two type parameters (`Map.Entry<String, Integer>` or `Map.Entry<Integer, String>`) is not relevant from a generics perspective: it's just a single type, hence you can replace the whole thing with `T`.

Answer (score 1):

What also may be helpful for you is that you can check the datatype of a variable with `instanceof` keyword. E.g.

`if (variable instanceof String) {
//do stuff
}`